# Error: expect(received).toBe(expected) // Object.is equality Expected: true Received: false at AppsMain

Tags: webdriver-io, headless

seeing the below error for tests that are running in production but they are running fine in staging environment

Error: expect(received).toBe(expected) // Object.is equality Expected: true Received: false at AppsMain

checked all config b/w stg and prod are same

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.